# Bindings not found

Tags: binding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhmi6.png)

This happens after running the front end of react app:[plugin:vite:react-swc] Bindings not found.
C:/Users/jonus/OneDrive/Desktop/real-estate-app/client/src/main.jsx
at Compiler. (C:\Users\jonus\OneDrive\Desktop\real-estate-app\client\node_modules@swc\core\index.js:228:19)
at Generator.next ()
at C:\Users\jonus\OneDrive\Desktop\real-estate-app\client\node_modules@swc\core\index.js:34:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (C:\Users\jonus\OneDrive\Desktop\real-estate-app\client\node_modules@swc\core\index.js:30:12)
at Compiler.transform (C:\Users\jonus\OneDrive\Desktop\real-estate-app\client\node_modules@swc\core\index.js:205:16)
at transform (C:\Users\jonus\OneDrive\Desktop\real-estate-app\client\node_modules@swc\core\index.js:347:21)
at transformWithOptions (file:///C:/Users/jonus/OneDrive/Desktop/real-estate-app/client/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react-swc/index.mjs:159:20)
at TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/Users/jonus/OneDrive/Desktop/real-estate-app/client/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react-swc/index.mjs:78:30)
at Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/jonus/OneDrive/Desktop/real-estate-app/client/node_modules/vite/dist/n

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.